# Execution of a Javascript Function Stops When A For Loop Completes Without Any Conditions Met

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an MVC 5, C# program which creates `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` in an ActionResult and passes it to a view as ViewData where I create "batchNumValues" from the "values" of the Dictionary key/value pairs.

`@{
   Dictionary<string, List<string>>.ValueCollection batchNumValues =          batchNumDict.Values;
}`

I created a Javascript function to validate a "batchNumber" against "batchNumValues."

When the passed "batchNumber" does match an entry in "batchNumValues" "true" is returned and everything is fine.  However, if no match is found, nothing further happens.  No return is made and any other code placed after the nested For loops is never executed.  Basically it appears as though the function simply stops executing.

I have spent quite a few hours researching this issue and was not able to find anything suggestive of an answer.

```
function validateBatchNumber(batchNumber) {

    var batchNumArray = @Html.Raw(javaSerial.Serialize(batchNumValues));

    for (var i = 0; i < $(batchNumArray).length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < $(batchNumArray[i]).length; j++) {
            if ($(batchNumArray[i])[j].replace(/\"/g, "") == batchNumber) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you wrapping your array accesses with jQuery calls? `$(batchNumArray[0])` could just be `batchNumArray[0]`. There's no reason to wrap it in a jQuery object.

Comment: Can you post the rendered version of this code?

Comment: Mike C - you're correct.  I originally was not wrapping the array accesses with jQuery calls but when things weren't working and I couldn't figure out why I just gave that a shot.

Comment: Geek Josh - to respond to your request I took a look at the rendered code.  What I saw is that because I was performing the `var batchNumArray = @Html.Raw(javaSerial.Serialize(batchNumValues));` inside of the function definition I had an array of 10, arrays of 200, entries each.  I thought it would be easier to show the render if I just moved the javaSerial call above the function definition.  Things then worked.  I don't know why it should make a difference but it did.  Thanks for your thoughts.